# "К оплате", допустимость выражения

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

Часто на кассах говорят: «К оплате такая-то сумма». А правильно ли это? Сумма, если подумать, нужна для оплаты. А что такое «к оплате»?

Сюда же можно отнести выражение "рекомендую к просмотру".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Таковы издержки сокращения - да и "оплачивают" не *сумму*, а услуги или расходы этой суммой. Предлог относится к опускаемому в формальном бухгалтерском выражении глаголу или причастию: **сумма** денежных средств, *выставленная* (причитающаяся, назначенная и пр.) **к оплате** чего-то.